# VSTS CI push images to Linux remote server

Tags: powershell, docker, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I have an ASP.NET Core solution and I am using Visual Studio Team Services Continuous Integration to build and push the images into the Azure Container registries repositories. Until now all are fine; now I am trying some way to push those images to a Linux Ubuntu Server that is also hosted in Azure, but the PowerShell on Target Machines won't execute the script to the remote server.

There are any way to make the server load the new images when they are available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dedicated Docker tasks, which are cross-platform, or you can use SSH task to run a script on a Linux machine using SSH.

Comment: thanks fir the response. Can you please give me more details about Docker task to run a script on a remote Linux machine?

Comment: I can't give you more information than the documentation can give you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=vsts